# How to parallelize a rule by input in Snakefile (with multiple outputs)

Tags: snakemake

I am very confused about how Snakemake works to parallelize jobs in a rule. I'd like to use a core per input (treating inputs separately, not with space between them), providing multiple outputs per input.

Here's an simplified example of my code:

```
# Globals ---------------------------------------------------------------------

datasets = ["dataset_S1", "dataset_S2"]
methods = ["pbs", "pbs_windowed", "ihs", "xpehh"]

# Rules ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

rule all:
    input:
        # Binary files
        expand("{dataset}/results_bin/persnp/{method}.feather", dataset=datasets, method=methods),
        expand("{dataset}/results_bin/pergene/{method}.feather", dataset=datasets, method=methods)


rule bin:
    input:
        "{dataset}/results_bin/convert2feather.R"
    output:
        "{dataset}/results_bin/persnp/{method}.feather",
        "{dataset}/results_bin/pergene/{method}.feather"
    threads:
        2
    shell:
        "Rscript {input}
```

If a run the code above using `snakemake -j2`, I ended up re-running each script per output method, which is not what I want. If I use the `expand()` function for the input and output in the bin rule as well, I would ending up using:

```
shell:
    """
    Rscript {input[0]}
    Rscript {input[1]}
    """
```

which I think it won't be possible to parallelize.

What should I do to take each input separately so that I can use one core for each?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx!

**EDIT**

Trying to better explain what my script does, and which behavior I expect from Snakemake. See my example folder structure:

```
.
├── dataset_S1
│   ├── data
│   │   └── data.vcf
│   ├── results_bin
│   │   └── convert2feather.R
│   ├── task2
│   │   └── script.py
│   └── task3
│       └── script.sh
└── dataset_S2
    ├── data
    │   └── data.vcf
    ├── results_bin
    │   └── convert2feather.R
    ├── task2
    │   └── script.py
    └── task3
        └── script.sh
```

As you can see, for each dataset, I have folders with the same structure and named scripts (although the content from the scripts may differ a bit). In my example, the script will read the "data.vcf" file, manipulate it, then create new folders and files in the respective dataset folder. It'll be repeating the overall tasks to both datasets. I'd like to do that in a way I'll be able to do the same with the scripts in the folder task2, task3, and so on...

For instance, the output from my pipeline in this example will be:

```
.
├── dataset_S1
│   ├── data
│   │   └── data.vcf
│   └── results_bin
│       ├── convert2feather.R
│       ├── pergene
│       │   ├── ihs.feather
│       │   ├── pbs.feather
│       │   ├── pbs_windowed.feather
│       │   └── xpehh.feather
│       └── persnp
│           ├── ihs.feather
│           ├── pbs.feather
│           ├── pbs_windowed.feather
│           └── xpehh.feather
└── dataset_S2
    ├── data
    │   └── data.vcf
    └── results_bin
        ├── convert2feather.R
        ├── pergene
        │   ├── ihs.feather
        │   ├── pbs.feather
        │   ├── pbs_windowed.feather
        │   └── xpehh.feather
        └── persnp
            ├── ihs.feather
            ├── pbs.feather
            ├── pbs_windowed.feather
            └── xpehh.feather
```

---

**EDIT2**

File and commands used:

```
(snakemake) cmcouto-silva@datascience-IB:~/cmcouto.silva@usp.br/lab_files/phd_data$ snakemake -j2 -p
# Globals ---------------------------------------------------------------------

datasets = ["dataset_S1", "dataset_S2"]
methods = ["pbs", "pbs_windowed", "ihs", "xpehh"]

# Rules ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

rule all:
    input:
        # Binary files
        expand("{dataset}/results_bin/persnp/{method}.feather", dataset=datasets, method=methods),
        expand("{dataset}/results_bin/pergene/{method}.feather", dataset=datasets, method=methods)

rule bin:
    input:
        "{dataset}/results_bin/convert2feather.R"
    output:
        expand("{{dataset}}/results_bin/persnp/{method}.feather", method=methods),
        expand("{{dataset}}/results_bin/pergene/{method}.feather", method=methods)
    threads:
        2
    shell:
        "Rscript {input}"
```

Output log:

```
(snakemake) cmcouto-silva@datascience-IB:~/cmcouto.silva@usp.br/lab_files/phd_data$ snakemake -j2 -p
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 2
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    2   bin
    3

[Wed Sep 30 23:47:55 2020]
rule bin:
    input: dataset_S1/results_bin/convert2feather.R
    output: dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: dataset=dataset_S1
    threads: 2

Rscript dataset_S1/results_bin/convert2feather.R
  Package "data.table" successfully loaded!
  Package "magrittr" successfully loaded!
  Package "snpsel" successfully loaded!
[Wed Sep 30 23:48:43 2020]
Finished job 1.
1 of 3 steps (33%) done

[Wed Sep 30 23:48:43 2020]
rule bin:
    input: dataset_S2/results_bin/convert2feather.R
    output: dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: dataset=dataset_S2
    threads: 2

Rscript dataset_S2/results_bin/convert2feather.R
  Package "data.table" successfully loaded!
  Package "magrittr" successfully loaded!
  Package "snpsel" successfully loaded!
[Wed Sep 30 23:49:41 2020]
Finished job 2.
2 of 3 steps (67%) done

[Wed Sep 30 23:49:41 2020]
localrule all:
    input: dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather
    jobid: 0

[Wed Sep 30 23:49:41 2020]
Finished job 0.
3 of 3 steps (100%) done
Complete log: /home/cmcouto-silva/cmcouto.silva@usp.br/lab_files/phd_data/.snakemake/log/2020-09-30T234755.741940.snakemake.log

(snakemake) cmcouto-silva@datascience-IB:~/cmcouto.silva@usp.br/lab_files/phd_data$ cat /home/cmcouto-silva/cmcouto.silva@usp.br/lab_files/phd_data/.snakemake/log/2020-09-30T234755.741940.snakemake.log
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 2
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    2   bin
    3

[Wed Sep 30 23:47:55 2020]
rule bin:
    input: dataset_S1/results_bin/convert2feather.R
    output: dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: dataset=dataset_S1
    threads: 2

Rscript dataset_S1/results_bin/convert2feather.R
[Wed Sep 30 23:48:43 2020]
Finished job 1.
1 of 3 steps (33%) done

[Wed Sep 30 23:48:43 2020]
rule bin:
    input: dataset_S2/results_bin/convert2feather.R
    output: dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: dataset=dataset_S2
    threads: 2

Rscript dataset_S2/results_bin/convert2feather.R
[Wed Sep 30 23:49:41 2020]
Finished job 2.
2 of 3 steps (67%) done

[Wed Sep 30 23:49:41 2020]
localrule all:
    input: dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/persnp/xpehh.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S1/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/pbs_windowed.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/ihs.feather, dataset_S2/results_bin/pergene/xpehh.feather
    jobid: 0

[Wed Sep 30 23:49:41 2020]
Finished job 0.
3 of 3 steps (100%) done
Complete log: /home/cmcouto-silva/cmcouto.silva@usp.br/lab_files/phd_data/.snakemake/log/2020-09-30T234755.741940.snakemake.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I getting it right that you have two input files (your scripts, one per dataset) for this rule and you want them to run in parallel?
If so, you need to give the snakemake call twice the amount of cores that you defined in the rule.

The `threads` field in the rule gives the number of cores you want to use on this rule per input/iteration. So, the first dataset will use 2 cores and the second dataset will also use 2 cores. To run them in parallel, you'd need to call `snakemake -j4`.

I hope I understood your problem, if not, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thank you, jafors! By running with `-j4` flag, using the scheme showed by @Manavalan, solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it appears to me there will be three "method" outfiles for each "dataset" infile. If so, this should work.

```py
rule bin:
    input:
        "{dataset}/results_bin/convert2feather.R"
    output:
        expand("{{dataset}}/results_bin/persnp/{method}.feather", method=methods),
        expand("{{dataset}}/results_bin/pergene/{method}.feather", method=methods)
```

Comment: You understood correctly (four method outfiles, actually, but you got it). However, I tried to run your code (without modifying the rule all) and it still run one script after another.

Comment: Glad that I wasn't far off. Could you post what snakemake does when pipeline is run?

Comment: Ok, I just updated the post with more information. Please let me know if I can explain it better.

Comment: I believe my solution already will result in the expected behavior laid out in your updated question. Could you show us snakemake command used and its logs?

Comment: Looks to me it is behaving as expected. It runs two jobs independently - one for `dataset_S1` and another for `dataset_S2`. Perhaps I am missing something here?

Comment: It runs two jobs independently, but not at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @Manavalan! Your answer (expand with wildcards), together with jafors' answer, solved my problem.